# Unable to understand d3js zoom functionality

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The following SIMPLE :) code gives following error. Please help me what mistake I am making to ZOOM on **onClick** on the Circle ?

Similarly I will be very thankful if someone can give some idea that if i want to zoom to 3rd Circle DIRECTLY without clicking on it; what should I do ?

```
ERROR: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at qr.call (d3.min.js:2)
    at SVGCircleElement.clicked (index.html:52)
    at SVGCircleElement.<anonymous> (d3.min.js:2)
```

And here is the code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1" />
        <title>Zoom & Pan</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.min.js"></script>

        <style type="text/css">

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            var width = 600, height = 350;
            var data = [
                { "r": 10, "cx": 100, "cy": 150 },
                { "r": 30, "cx": 200, "cy": 150 },
                { "r": 15, "cx": 300, "cy": 150 }

            ];
            var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height)
                .call( 
                        d3.zoom()
                        .scaleExtent([1, 7])
                        .on("zoom", zoom)
                );

            const g = svg.append("g");

            g.selectAll("circle")
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append("circle")
                //.attr("fill", function (d) { return d.color; })
                .attr("fill", (d, i) => d3.interpolateRainbow(i / 3))
                .on("click", clicked)
                .attr("r", function (d) { return d.r; })
                .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.cx; })
                .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.cy; });


            function clicked(d,i,nodes) {
                console.log(nodes);

                svg.transition().duration(750).call(
                    zoom.transform,
                    d3.zoomIdentity.translate(width / 2, height / 2).scale(40).translate(-d.cx, -d.cy),
                    d3.mouse(svg.node())
                );

            }

            function zoom() {
                g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
            }

        </script>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: What version of d3 are you using?

Comment: console.log(d3) showed me 

version: "5.14.2"

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `zoom.transform` is not a thing. You have created a function called `zoom`, if that is important then you'll need to create another variable called something else, e.g. zoomer, probably in window scope, like `width` and `height`:

```
var zoomer = d3.zoom();
```

Then in your click handler change `zoom.transform` to `zoomer.transform`:

```
function clicked(d,i,nodes) {
  console.log(nodes);

  svg.transition().duration(750).call(
    zoomer.transform, //change here
    d3.zoomIdentity.translate(width / 2, height / 2).scale(40).translate(-d.cx, -d.cy),
    d3.mouse(svg.node())
  );
}
```

If you don't need the `zoom` function, then delete that and create the `zoom` variable like the `zoomer` one above and don't change the click handler.

Comment: I have changed the code as suggested by you but unfortunately 'single click on circle is still not working'. Plus if I remove the 'zoom' function then double-click-zooming and wheel-zooming also doesn't work.

Comment: my new code is like this 

`var zoomer = d3.zoom();
        function clicked(d,i,nodes) {
            //console.log(nodes);
            
            svg.transition().duration(500).call(
                zoomer.transform,
                d3.zoomIdentity.translate(width / 2, height / 2).scale(10).translate(-d.cx, -d.cy),
                d3.mouse(svg.node())
            );
            
        }

        function zoom() {
            g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
        }`

Comment: First, you should remove the console.log(nodes) as that seems to be causing a massive delay. I'll look further when I've got time.

Comment: Sure take your time. I have observed that when I 'single click' a circle and then 'double click' anywhere in sequence then it works as required. In other words 
when I click a circle and then double click anywhere within svg the clicked circle get zoomed in.